# User input by using Class object in Python

Tags: python, oop

The question:

A user interface contains two typs of user input controls: TextInput, which accepts all characters all characters and NumbericInputs, which accepts only digits.

Implement the class TextInput that contains:

- Method *add(self, character)* – adds the given character to the current value
- Method *get_value(self)* – returns the current value

Implement the class Numericinput that:

- Inherits TextInput
- Overrides the add method so that each non-numeric character is
  ignored

For example, the following code should output “10”:

```
input = NumericInput()
input.add(“1”)
input.add(“a”)
input.add(“0”)
print(input.get_value())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GR4g.png)

My code in python,

```
class TextInput:
    def __init__(self, txt):
        self.txt = txt

    def getTxt(self):
        return self.txt


class NumericInput(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, num):
        super().__init__(str(num))  # Call the superclass's __init__ method to set txt
        self.num = str(num)  # Convert the number to a string

    def add(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, int) or value.isdigit():
            self.num += str(value)

    def get_value(self):
        return self.num


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input = NumericInput()  
    input.add("1")  
    input.add("a") 
    input.add("0")  
    print(input.get_value())
```

I got error when run the solution,

```
Error running solution, see below

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "userinput.py", line 23, in <module>
    input = NumericInput()  # Initialize NumericInput with an initial value
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: NumericInput.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecOwL.png)

Can anyone help? How do I fix my error?

Comment: Please do not use images in your question.

Comment: The error message says that you are _missing 1 required positional argument: 'num'_ when creating an instance of the class `NumericInput`. It does so, since `__init__` takes one parameter called `num`. According to your implementation of `NumericInput.__init__`, your code should read `input = NumericInput(42)` or similar.

Comment: Your comment says `# Initialize NumericInput with an initial value` but that's not what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `NumericInput`'s initializer expects a parameter and you didn't pass it in instantiation.

You can do the following:

```py
class TextInput:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._value: str = ""

    def add(self, character: str) -> None:
        self._value += character

    def get_value(self) -> str:
        return self._value


class NumericInput(TextInput):
    def add(self, character: str) -> None:
        if character.isdigit():
            super().add(character)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    inp = NumericInput()
    inp.add("1")
    inp.add("a")
    inp.add("0")
    print(inp.get_value())  # "10"
```

Here are couple of changes:

- Always respect to the naming convention in Python
- You should have `get_value` in parent class.
- Your parent class should also have the ability to add character.
- You always get a "character"(stated in the question) so this condition is never going to be true: `isinstance(value, int)`

---

If you want to accept initial value while instantiating, you can do:

```py
class TextInput:
    def __init__(self, initial_value: str = "") -> None:
        self._value: str = initial_value

    def add(self, character: str) -> None:
        self._value += character

    def get_value(self) -> str:
        return self._value


class NumericInput(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, initial_value: str = "") -> None:
        super().__init__()
        for c in initial_value:
            self.add(c)

    def add(self, character: str) -> None:
        if character.isdigit():
            super().add(character)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    inp = NumericInput("1boo")
    inp.add("1")
    inp.add("a")
    inp.add("0")
    print(inp.get_value())  # 110
```

Comment: Got it, thanks! It works!

Comment: @Barney-LoveStudy You may mark it as the answer if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

When you create object of **NumericInput** you didn't provide any argument but it requires a positional argument **num** . You can create object like **input = NumericInput("5")**